# why does facebook's thumbnail cache use wrong image and debugger shows correct image?

Tags: facebook, sharing, elgg

i have written a plugin for the elgg social networking platform which supports sharing links to other social networks.
mostly this is ok.

i am noticing though that facebook often shows incorrect images for the video thumbnails and other sites, such as google+ are ok.

the url i am passing in to the sharer page is correct and when i use the facebook debugging tool, i see the correct image - e.g. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.infiniteeureka.com%2Fvideos%2Fwatch%2F6980%2Fwater-as-primary-healing-agent-dis-ease-is-commonly-due-to-dehydration

as an example - this is the url that the plugin currently outputs for facebook, when sharing a video on my site:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=water+as+primary+healing+agent+-+dis-ease+is+commonly+due+to+dehydration&p[summary]=description&p[url]=https://www.infiniteeureka.com/videos/watch/6980/water-as-primary-healing-agent-dis-ease-is-commonly-due-to-dehydration&p[images][0]=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.infiniteeureka.com%2Fmod%2Fvideolist%2Fthumbnail.php%3Fjoindate%3D1293022025%26guid%3D6980%26owner_guid%3D2%26size%3Dlarge

when i share this to facebook, i see a thumbnail for another video which i shared days earlier, which has a different url. (edit: i now notice that i can choose from 3 images in facebook and one of them is the correct one - so facebook is building an array of 2 incorrect images in some way and is defaulting to an incorrect one.)

anyone know?

Comment: I have a similar problem, but with the sharer.php?s=100 URL with customized title, description & image. The customized title and description are not showing up anymore, and I have a caroussel of two old images !

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem often as well. Try to make your image around 1080px # 1080px and see if that helps. The other options is to try and lazy load all the other images so facebook doesn't pick them up as I presume the thumbnail you are referring to is on the page?